# Confidence interval from se.fit of the prediction of a weibull survreg model in R "survival"

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-error, weibull, survival

I'd like to learn about how to get confidence interval from the prediction of value and standard error from a weibull survreg model in R "survival".

[R doc for predict.survreg](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/predict.survreg.html) has an example showing a plot not only gives the `fit` of the prediction of a weibull survreg model but also the `fit+2*se.fit` and `fit-2*se.fit`. Then the range from `fit-2*se.fit` to `fit+2*se.fit` corresponds to what confidence interval? And for a given confidence interval, how to choose the *n* for `fit +/- n*se.fit` to obtain that confidence interval? Following is the code:

```
lfit <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data=lung)
pct <- 1:98/100   # The 100th percentile of predicted survival is at +infinity
ptime <- predict(lfit, newdata=data.frame(ph.ecog=2), type='quantile', p=pct, se=TRUE)
matplot(cbind(ptime$fit, ptime$fit + 2*ptime$se.fit, ptime$fit - 2*ptime$se.fit)/30.5, 1-pct, xlab="Months", ylab="Survival", type='l', lty=c(1,2,2), col=1)
```

For normal distribution, I think for 95% confidence interval, can use `fit +/- 1.96*se.fit`. I'm not sure whether it works for a weibull survreg model.

Comment: Please share your example data and what your expected output looks like

Comment: Voting to migrate.